# facebook post on user wall with permission

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using below code to post on my friends wall.

The problem with this code is,it is prompting and when i click share only it post but i want it to post in user wall,he's has already granted the permission.

```
     function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){
     FB.ui(
     {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: '',
     attachment: {
        name: name,
        caption: '',
        description: (description),
        href: hrefLink
     },
     action_links: [
        { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
      ],
      user_prompt_message: userPrompt
    },
    function(response) {

    });
     }
      streamPublish();
```

I tried removing that user_prompt_message but it still prompts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the feed dialog there; this opens a Facebook-provided dialog for the user to preview and confirm the content before it posts to their feed.

If you want to post directly to the users feed using the `publish_stream` extended permission you need to make an API call directly to `/{USER ID}/feed` - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed for more information.

Just remember that the user still needs to consent to each post made on their behald, it's just not required that you use Facebook's feed dialog for doing so